# Bootstrap v4 columns won't float with flex enabled

Tags: css-float, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap v4 the css `float` directive will not work on columns if `$enable-flex: true;` is set within Bootstrap's SCSS variables. This is due to the way `flex` works.

How can the same effect be achieved with `flex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reverse container's row direction**

One option is to float everything inside a `row` to the right. We can add this to the containing element (such as a `row`) to achieve this:

```
flex-direction:row-reverse;
-webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse; /* Safari 6.1+ */
```

**EDIT**: Ended up making a mixin and class for this in a Bootstrap-y way if anyone is interested (use `.row-reverse` like `row`):

```
@mixin make-row-reverse($gutter: $grid-gutter-width) {
  @if $enable-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  } @else {
    @include clearfix();
    > * {
      float: right;
    }
  }
  margin-left:  ($gutter / -2);
  margin-right: ($gutter / -2);
}

// Row reverse
//
// A row with a reversed render direction.

@if $enable-grid-classes {
  .row-reverse {
    @include make-row-reverse();
  }
}
```

**Order the individual elements**

Another option would be to specify the order the columns should be in inside the container using the `order` directive. Set this on one of the contained columns to make it the second column in the row:

```
order: 2;
```

**Self alignment**

I'm putting this here purely because I think this is the way it *should* be done, but this is not working for me as intended. There is also an `align-self` directive for `flex` where passing `flex-end` to it would cause the element to render at the opposide side of the flex column or flex row. Be great if anyone has anymore information on this, but this didn't work for my use case. Perhaps this might help someone else though.